# About derivative of area of moving semi-circle

Tags: derivatives

A metallic wire bend in the form a semi-circle of radius 0.1 m is moved in direction parallel to its plane, But perpendicular to a magnetic field b=20mT with a velocity of 10m/s. What is the induced emf in the wire?

Im stuck at finding $\frac {dA}{dt}$ of the semi-circle.It should be 2$\pi$rv but the books says its 2rv.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The electric current flows through a loop (drawn in red colour), which is the border of the area $A$.

The circuit is made up of an upper stationary wire, a lower stationary wire (both drawn in black) and the moving semic-circle shaped wire (the red border of the semicircle):

[image: circuit]

$A$ is the sum of the area of a growing rectangle (the shaded area in the image above) and the constant semi-circle area (not shaded).

We can write $A$ as
$$
A = v t \cdot 2 r + \pi r
$$

An animated version can be found [here](https://ggbm.at/xkAf3Fex).

Then the derivative of $A$ regarding time $t$ is
$$
\dot{A} = 2rv
$$
Update: I assume a setup like this (with a semi-circular bar, not a straight one):

[image]

(Source [Wikipedia](https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bewegter_Leiter_im_Feld-Feldlinienbild.svg))

Comment: rectangle? where, how? please explain, it was formed in a semi-circle

Comment: i think the question is saying that if the length of the wire is L, then its formed in a semi-circle with radius = L/(2*pi), and not the shape you have given. am i wrong?

Comment: this setup is with a bar, in my question its a semi circle. i am not getting it.

Comment: You have to replace the straight bar with a semicircle shaped bar.

Comment: After replacing too, i dont see any rectangle. i also have cut a paper in shape of semi circle imitating the situation, but i dont see any rectangle :(

Comment: I updated the question, changed the first image and added a link to an animated version. Please check both and then re-read the answer. Try to understand the equations for $A$ and its derivative $\dot{A}$.

Comment: Wow. Thank u for all your effort. Understood :)